# Delete list item - Android concept

Tags: android, listview, user-experience

What is Android's concept of deleting a list item? I thought of something like long-pressing it which will pop-up a dialog box to confirm / reject...
But would like to know what is the most popular way of doing it in Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is regarding to UX design. Generally speaking, the most popular approach of deleting items are:

1. Long press and pop up context menu
2. On action bar, entering selection mode and then choose the action
3. Slide to right/left and display a delete indicator on the item

You might choose/combine appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link may explain everything you need for the deletion in list view.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48112/typical-android-app-behavior-for-deleting-data-from-a-list